# Error in calculating Floor() from SQL

Tags: sql, floor

I need to calculate numbers of money notes needed for salary preparation. 
I have problem with the last column, i.e. USD1.

I will to get the value for USD1 = 2.

```
DECLARE @GrossPay Decimal(12,2)
SET @GrossPay = 132.78

SELECT
    @GrossPay,
    FLOOR(@GrossPay/100) AS USD100,
    FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50) AS USD50,
    FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50)/20) AS USD20,
    FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50 - (FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50)/20))*20)/10) AS USD10,
FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50 - (FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50)/20))*20 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50 - (FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50)/20))*20)/10))*10)/5) AS USD5,
FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50 - (FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50)/20))*20 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay -
FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50 - (FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50)/20))*20)/10))*10-(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50 - (FLOOR((@GrossPay -
FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50)/20))*20 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50 - (FLOOR((@GrossPay -
FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100 -(FLOOR((@GrossPay - FLOOR(@GrossPay/100)*100)/50))*50)/20))*20)/10))*10)/5))*5)/1) AS USD1
```

Sorry for such a long query.

You can copy and paste the above Sql Query and execute it, then you will understnad what i mean. Hope that anyone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ummmm....if you're getting `floor(2.78)==2`, then the `floor` function is working exactly as it's supposed to.

Comment: pls, retain that part of the select that returns 3, only a bozotron can read your code, no offence :)

Comment: How many times do you have to type the word "FLOOR" before you start thinking there must be a better way to approach this?

Comment: Thank you all for the good lesson for me, appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of your expressions can be simplified if you realise you don't need to subtract the calculated previous amounts (the only one I can't get a decent expression for at the moment is `USD10`). For instance, the `USD1` column is always going to be a value between 0 and 4, based on the remainder of dividing the whole amount by 5.

That's the definition of the modulo operator, in SQL this is [`%`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx), so we can have:

```
(CONVERT(int,@GrossPay)%5) as USD1
```

As I say, most of the others can also be calculated by using modulo (except USD10, still trying to think of a simplification for that). I've also introduced another variable, called `@GrossPayInt`, because it handles the rounding automatically:

```
DECLARE @GrossPay Decimal(12,2) SET @GrossPay = 132.78
DECLARE @GrossPayInt int SET @GrossPayInt = @GrossPay

SELECT @GrossPay,
    @GrossPayInt/100 as USD100,
    (@GrossPayInt%100)/50 as USD50,
    (@GrossPayInt%50)/20 as USD20,
    CASE WHEN (@GrossPayInt%100)/10 IN (1,3,6,8) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as USD10 as USD10,
    (@GrossPayInt%10)/5 as USD5,
    (@GrossPayInt%5) as USD1
```

If anyone else can suggest a good short expression for USD10, I think that this is done.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [ROUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx):

```
SELECT ROUND(2.78,0)
```

Alternatively, adding `0.5` will make `floor` round up instead of floor:

```
SELECT FLOOR(2.78+0.5)
```